# Remove "In" from inproceedings entries in bib file

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing my thesis on Overleaf. For my conference references, it shows "In" in the references. For example:

"Hong Chang, Dit-Yan Yeung, and Yimin Xiong. Super-resolution through neighbor embedding. In IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition., volume 1, pages 1–8, 2004.

I want to remove "In" in the references ("In IEEE Computer..."). Does anyone know how I can do this please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[table]{sfuthesis}

\begin{document}
\backmatter%

\addtoToC{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
```

My references file is with format .bib as follows:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
 CTLdash_repeated_names = "no"
}

@inproceedings{chang2004super,
 title={Super-resolution through neighbor embedding},
 author={Chang, Hong and Yeung, Dit-Yan and Xiong, Yimin},
 booktitle={Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and 
Pattern Recognition. CVPR 2004.},
 volume={1},
 pages={1--8},
 year={2004},
 organization={IEEE}
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It sounds like you are using bibtex, but please confirm that.  It would also be helpful to know what document class you are using and the bibliography style you have specified.  Ideally, a small compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` will provide the ability for potential helpers to copy/paste the code and experiment.

Comment: Thank you barbara. I just edited the question

Comment: Please show a  bib entry that generates the `In ` prefix when use with the `IEEEtran` bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico I just edited it. Thanks